# TensorRT seems to lack common functionality

Tags: python, tensorrt

I've recently encountered such an amazing tool called tensorRT, but because I don't have NVIDIA GPU on my laptop, I decided to use Google Collab instead to play around with this technology.

I used simple pip command to install necessary libraries, including ones for CUDA management

```
pip install nvidia-tensorrt --index-url https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
pip install pycuda
```

After installation everything seems to be ready for usage. However, it turns out that some of the common methods simply does not exist.

When I tried to create `tensorRT Engine` via

```
builder = trt.Builder(trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO))
network = builder.create_network(batch_size)
engine = builder.build_cuda_engine(network)
```

It throws exception, `'tensorrt.tensorrt.Builder' has no attribute 'build_cuda_engine'`, despite the fact, that it suppose to.

[image]

Am I missing out on some important installation, or I just use some deprecated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorRT is indeed quite a nice tool for inference. It is tricky to use at the beginning but quickly becomes logical. Follow the python examples available on their github [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/release/8.6/samples/python).

To solve your particular problem, meaning, programmatically building a TensorRT engine follow this structure :

```py
explicit_batch = 1 << (int)(
    trt.NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag.EXPLICIT_BATCH)

with trt.Builder(self.TRT_LOGGER) as builder, \
    builder.create_network(explicit_batch) as network, \
        trt.OnnxParser(network, self.TRT_LOGGER) as parser:

    with open("model.onnx", 'rb') as model:
        parser.parse(model.read())

    builder.max_workspace_size = 1 << 30
    config = builder.create_builder_config()
    config.max_workspace_size = 1 << max_workspace_size
    config.set_flag(trt.BuilderFlag.GPU_FALLBACK)
    config.set_flag(trt.BuilderFlag.FP16)


    engine = builder.build_engine(network, config)
    with open("result.engine", "wb") as f:
        f.write(engine.serialize())
```

It is quite a basic snippet of code which should fix your current issue. Following the samples and following this structure should fix your issues.

[This Yolov7 github repository](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) also supports TensorRT and has a complete implementation of how to export your model and this [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/tools/YOLOv7trt.ipynb) about how to infer it.

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helped :)